# Why StringBuffer and StringBuilder append methods discard the value returned by the super call

Tags: java

This is a question out of curiousity.
Today I took a look at the implementations of `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`. Here's the `append()` method:

```
public StringBuilder append(String str) {
    super.append(str);
    return this;
}
```

`AbstractStringBuilder.append(str)` also returns `this`. Are there any benefits of discarding the return value (in `StringBuilder.append(..)`) and returning `this` again, instead of casting the return value of the `super` call to the current concrete implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first thought is that casting can be expensive, so if it can be avoided that would be best.

Comment: It's not expensive compared to most other things, but if it can be (easily) avoided in a *very* frequently called API method then that's clearly a good thing.

Comment: It's free actually (if JITed)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it has to do with the cost of casting.

My opinion is that the method has been written like this in case future needs require to do more than what's done in the super class.

```
public StringBuilder append(String str) {
    super.append(str);

    // do something more?

    return this;
}
```

Or the method definition has been auto-generated by the IDE at the time the class was written. Or it's just a matter of coding style.

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
public StringBuilder append(String str) {
    return (StringBuilder) super.append(str);
}
```

is quite ugly. It isn't even shorter.

(There are languages that support this [directly](http://scalada.blogspot.com/2008/02/thistype-for-chaining-method-calls.html). Something like:

```
abstract class AbstractStringBuilder{
  type T = this.type
  def append(str : String) : T = ...
}

abstract class StringBuilder{
  //already defined by AbstractStringBuilder return type is StringBuilder
}
```

)

Comment: The alternative is also slower as a cast is performed.